# Flutter get request on a valid url returning 404 Error

Tags: html, json, flutter, dart, get

I am trying to create a project using the HackerNews API and I am issuing a get request to try to fetch JSON data about the top-stories using the following endpoint - https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json. I am issuing the get request using the http dart package.

pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^1.3.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
  http: ^0.12.2
  path: ^1.7.0
  intl: ^0.16.1
  rxdart: ^0.25.0
```

The get request runs however when I try to decode the JSON information in the body of the response object, I get the following error.

```
Exception has occurred.
FormatException (FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
<!DOCTYPE html>
^
)
```

My code is as follows:

```dart
 Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds() async {
    //root is the base URL as is 'http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0'
    final String url = '$root/topstories.json'; 
    print(url); //prints out the valid API endpoint
    final response = await client.get(url);
    print(response.body); //prints out some HTML, see below
    final ids = json.decode(response.body); //error
    return ids.cast<int>();
  }
```

The HTML displayed by printing the response.body:

```
I/flutter ( 7425): <!DOCTYPE html>
I/flutter ( 7425): <html lang=en>
I/flutter ( 7425):   <meta charset=utf-8>
I/flutter ( 7425):   <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
I/flutter ( 7425):   <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
I/flutter ( 7425):   <style>
I/flutter ( 7425):     *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}html{background:#fff;color:#222;padding:15px}body{margin:7% auto 0;max-width:390px;min-height:180px;padding:30px 0 15px}* > body{background:url(//www.google.com/images/errors/robot.png) 100% 5px no-repeat;padding-right:205px}p{margin:11px 0 22px;overflow:hidden}ins{color:#777;text-decoration:none}a img{border:0}@media screen and (max-width:772px){body{background:none;margin-top:0;max-width:none;padding-right:0}}#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat;margin-left:-5px}@media only screen and (min-resolution:192dpi){#logo{background:url(//www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_150x54dp.png) no-repeat 0% 0%/100% 100%;-moz-border-image:url(//www.google.com/images/brand
```

How do I go about it and fix this error? Thanks

EDIT:
The client is an instance of the Client class from the HTTP package and is an instance variable of the class.

```dart
class NewsApiProvider implements Source {
  final Client client = Client();

  Future<List<int>> fetchTopIds() async {
    final String url = '$root/topstories.json';
    print(url);
    final response = await client.get(url);
    print(response.body);
    final ids = jsonDecode(response.body);
    return ids.cast<int>();
  }
```

Comment: what is client in this ??

Comment: I'll edit the question and include the client information

Comment: final response = await http.get(url); try to replace this line and check it

Comment: I tried that, it did not change the error.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your data which data you have passed. Because I have checked your params in postman.You have passed wrong params.

You have passed wrong url. Please use this `https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json`

[image]

Comment: Hey, I got my API endpoint from the hackernews documentation - https://github.com/HackerNews/API, following the API endpoint on my browser seems to display correct information.

Comment: @Akashvshroff Please now check my post I have now edited my post. And please let me know it is running or not.

Comment: Hey, that is the exact API url that I have been using.

Answer (score 0):

i got this type of response in postman check the endpoint proper

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I apologise, it was my mistake, apparently the API now requires you to add a print=pretty tag at the end.

This is the valid endpoint:
https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty

I find it strange that the code did not work without the pretty print tag, but it is working with it now.